# Using Spring AOP how can I replace a method with another one during runtime?

Tags: java, methods, spring-aop

I am new to Spring AOP. WHat I figured out till now is, during runtime we can call a user defined method (advice) before or after a method call. We can also change variable value assignments inside a method.

Now I want to replace a method call with another method during runtime. Suppose in a Java code I have method A() being called. During runtime with the help of AOP configuration file I want to call method B() instead of A() at the same position of A().

Please let me know how to implement this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try around advice, here is example from Spring docs

```
@Aspect
public class AroundExample {

  @Around("com.xyz.myapp.SystemArchitecture.businessService()")
  public Object doBasicProfiling(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
    // start stopwatch
    Object retVal = pjp.proceed();
    // stop stopwatch
    return retVal;
  }

}
```

you can skip original method call and call any other method instead